# How many exponentiations can the Shamir algorithm reduce?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, ds.algorithms

The Shamir's algorithm is depicted as follows (cited from

[Handbook of Applied Cryptography](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/), chapter 14, algorithm 14.88, page 618)

### Shamir's algorithm

**INPUT**: group elements $g_0,g_1,\dots, g_{k-1}$ and non-negative $t$-bit integers $e_0,e_1,\dots, e_{k-1}$.

**OUTPUT**:$g_0^{e_0}g_1^{e_1}\dots g_{k-1}^{e_{k-1}}$

1. *Precomputation*. For $i$ from 0 to $2^k-1$: $G_i \gets \Pi_{j=0}^{k-1}g_j^{i_j}$ where $i=(i_{k-1}\dots i_0)_2$.
2. $A\gets1$
3. For $i$ from 1 to $t$ do : $A \gets A$, $A \gets A \cdot G_{I_i}$
4. Return($A$)

I wonder; how many exponentiations can the Shamir algorithm reduce? That's to say, usually it needs $k$ exponentiations to compute $g_0^{e_0}g_1^{e_1}\dots g_{k-1}^{e_{k-1}}$; however if we use the algorithm in the above, then how many exponentiations does it amount to when calculating $g_0^{e_0}g_1^{e_1}\dots g_{k-1}^{e_{k-1}}$?

P.S. Actually, this question appears in [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/17758/how-many-exponentiations-can-the-shamir-algorithm-reduce). I think it's more proper to ask in this section. However, as I'm a newer I cannot flag or delete this same question from https://crypto.stackexchange.com/.  I'm sorry to do this..

Comment: Cross-posted on Crypto.SE: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/17758/351.  Please don't cross-post on multiple SE sites; that is [prohibited by site rules](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/160917).  If you need to move a question to a different site, you can click "flag" underneath the question to flag it for moderator attention and ask them to migrate it -- but don't cross-post or re-post the same thing on multiple SE sites.  Thank you!

Comment: I tried to flag this question, but it doesn't work, I don't know why

Comment: What is $I_i$ in step 3 of the algorithm? Also, it seems like the "A<-A" step in 3 would not affect the output...

Comment: @Abel Molina: you can refer the link that I give for details